# Posting MongoDB data using angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have written the code to retrieve the data from mongodb using nodejs, but when I try to post that data using angular js, it's not working.

Here is the nodejs code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/shru';
var findRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor =db.collection('shruthi').find( );
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    findRestaurants(db, function() {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

This worked fine, I am able to retrieve the data. My database name is shru and my collection name is shruthi. This is the data what I have retrieved:

```
{ _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'VÍZrg¸ûì®¸*Ð' },
              name: 'shruts' }
{ _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'VÍZzg¸ûì®¸*Ñ' },
              name: 'vani' }
```

When I try to post this data using mongodb its not working fine. Can anyone explain me how to do this? How do I post the above data using angular js?

Answer (score 0):

Use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) for models and db communication. And on top of that create a server that listens to a POST request and then save data in mongo with mongoose.

For a web server I suggest [express](http://expressjs.com/) as a framework.